# How to detect the Normal Vector of the Vuforia Detected Ground Plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am facing the following Issue in Vuforia

after the Ground Plane Surface has been Detected, I am inserting a 3D model Dynamically at the PlaneIndicator position, 
but actually,
the inserted 3D object appears to be slanted to the front and not Setting vertical (90 degrees) on the Surface,

How can I solve this issue? Here is my code for rotating the object.

```
avatar.transform.position = PlaneIndecator.PlaneIndicator.transform.position; // Fix the Rotation 
avatar.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity; 
avatar.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity; // Rotate the Avatar to Face the Camera 
Vector3 target = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x,avatar.transform.position.y,
                                 Camera.main.transform.position.z); 
avatar.transform.LookAt(target);
```

Comment: Is the object you placed have euler angles of `(0,0,0)` in Editor?

Comment: Yes it is, i slove it using the following : 
// Place the avatar on the Plane Indicator Position avatar.transform.position = PlaneIndecator.PlaneIndicator.transform.position; // Fix the Rotation avatar.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity; avatar.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity; // Rotate the Avatar to Face the Camera Vector3 target = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x,avatar.transform.position.y,Camera.main.transform.position.z); avatar.transform.LookAt(target);

Comment: yeah , you're right!! the Rotation Should Be Around Local X axis